# Is it possible to run a gradle plugin without android studio?

Tags: android-studio, firebase, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

To use firebase I need to use the [The Google Services Gradle Plugin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/gradle/) however I m not under android studio. I already downloaded from maven the google-services-3.0.0.jar but what to do with it? is their any way to make it running outside android studio ? else what exactly this plugin do ? is it possible to do it manually ?

Comment: It is possible. Gradle is just a build tool. Android studio uses Gradle to describe, build and run your project. Gradle plugin is something you add to your `build.gradle` script. You can still use the script in any other tool, or simply from the command line. But all that is too broad to explain here.

Comment: Sounds like an answer @sm4! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible.

Gradle is just a build tool. Android studio uses Gradle to describe, build and run your project. Gradle plugin is something you add to your `build.gradle` script. While it's theoretically possible to use it outside Gradle, it's not meant to be used that way.

You can still use the Gradle script in any IDE that supports Gradle, or simply run it from the command line.

The only thing you need in your Gradle project is the following line:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```